# how to dismiss my current view

Tags: iphone, view, hide

hi i am having text view and on it one button to move to main view ,but i am using this is not working for me..

BackButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    BackButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [BackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [BackButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
and my method for back is 
-(void) back{

what should i place here to current view to dismiss.........
}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self removeFromSuperview];
```